# How to make a Windows 7 USB on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, usb-creator

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed, but would also like to dual boot Windows 7 aswell mainly for games. I have downloaded a Windows 7 ISO but the Startup Disk creator will not allow me to select it, so I cannot proceed to make the USB. If I was on Windows and I wanted to make a Windows USB I would just use command prompt, go to disk part and make the USB bootable and extract the ISO to the USB. Is there any way I can do this in terminal or a program that will do this for me? Or a way to get the Startup Disk Creator to make a Windows USB. I have been told that the startup disk creator only works on Ubuntu/Linux ISOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `winusb` to create a bootable USB drive.

[image]

To install on Ubuntu 14.04

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight`

`sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list"`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install winusb`